# Membership Form without Contribution Request

Tags: civicontribute, civimember

Is there a way to make a membership signup form that does not ask for a donation?

Answer (score 3):

Ben,

You can create **zero** membership fee membership type and include it on contribution page and turn off 'CONTRIBUTION AMOUNTS SECTION ENABLED' under Amounts tab of contribution page.

[image]